# How to get a value of a key in an array in lua?

Tags: arrays, lua, key-value

How to get a value of a key in an array:

```
local animals = {
    ["Pig"] = {weight= 600, count= 100},
    ["Cow"] = {weight= 500, count= 10}
}
```

I want to get weight of the pig and count of the cow.
I've tried to print something like this, but nothing works...

```
for key, value in pairs (animals) do
        -- PRINT PIG'S WEIGHT
        -- PRINT COW'S COUNT
end
```

Comment: `pairs` is for iterating trough table, not normally accessing keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
print(animals.Pig.weight)
print(animals.Cow.count)
```

Comment: Ty, LoL :D I,ve found another solution too: print(animals[1].weight)

Comment: @WojciechGlapa, `animals[1].weight` cannot work given the code you've posted.